# OneDrive.app keeps getting removed from Login Items

Tags: login-items

I want the OneDrive.app to start automatically on startup. I add it to the Login Items section but it gets removed from there after some time automatically. How can I fix this? I am using Big Sur and have version 22.186.0904 of OneDrive.app installed.